# Postgres PHP error from dev consoles on PDO command

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql

My page has an html form with seven fields for items like email, first name last name, etc.  I call a jQuery Ajax function from the click event of the form's button.  It passes the form data serialized, and submits it to a php script:

```
function CollectData() {
    form_data = $('form').serialize()
    /*form_data = $('form').serializeArray()*/
    console.log("CollectData");
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting");
    console.log(form_data);
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function (responseText) {
            /*console.log(responseText);*/
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

All of the console.log outputs in the jQuery function show in the dev console in both Firefox and Chrome.  The third console.log shows the form data, and everything is correct.  Here is the serialized version:

```
datefield=2019%2F7%2F6&email_field=mj%40abc.com&firstname=mary&lastname=jones&password=default00&comments=no&checkbox=true
```

My problem is that whether I pass the data using serialize() or serializeArray() I get the "Okay I failed" error in the dev consoles of both FF and Chrome.

Here is the php script (register.php):

```
<?php
// PHP file upload using PDO
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);

$params = [
    'host' => '000.000.000.000',
    'port' => '5432'
    'user' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'pwd' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'db' => 'dbase01' ];

try {
$pdo->beginTransaction();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO qsq01 ('"
. implode("','", $fields) . "') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($data as $row) $stmt->execute($row);
    $pdo->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    $pdo->rollBack();
}
?>
```

(The host, user and password have been replaced with "dummy" values for this post.)

The dev consoles in both FF and Chrome show the fallback error from the jQuery script (console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);).  Both consoles simply show:  Okay, I failed[object Object].

This is my first experience using php to insert records into a Postgres database. Something about my php script does not work, but the dev consoles don't report any other error information.

Thanks for any ideas on why my php script fails.

UPDATE:  the php error log at /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Jul 06 06:25:02.235252 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8217] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 06 06:25:02.235273 2019] [core:notice] [pid 8217] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Jul 06 21:34:23.181644 2019] [php7:emerg] [pid 31280] [client 73.35.150.123:52161] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''user'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' in /var/www/html/register.php on line 9, referer: http://000.000.000.0/
```

Where the final IP address has been replaced with zeroes.

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP error log?

Comment: I'm reading it right now.  It's long, so I'll post back with relevent-sounding errors.

Comment: I just updated my question with the most recent error.log entries.

Comment: The most relevant one looks like "expecting ']' in /var/www/html/register.php on line 9, referer: http://000.000.000.0/ " but line 9 would not have a "]" unless I don't understand how the log counts line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''user'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' in /var/www/html/register.php on line 9, referer: http://000.000.000.0/

You're missing a `,` after `'port' => '5432'` in your array declaration.

This

```
$params = [
    'host' => '000.000.000.000',
    'port' => '5432'
    'user' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'pwd' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'db' => 'dbase01' ];
```

Should be

```
$params = [
    'host' => '000.000.000.000',
    'port' => '5432',
    'user' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'pwd' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'db' => 'dbase01' ];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will add the comma after 5432.  For you other comments, this is Postgres, not MySQL -- are your comments still relevant to Postgres?

Comment: @RTC222 I've never used postgres, but from a quick search i don't think you use back ticks in postgres. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The comma after 5432 got rid of the syntax errors.  The remaining issue is that pdo_pgsql is not found, apparently not enabled.  See my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918536/php-a2enmod-does-not-exist-for-file-that-does-exist